# Pull image from folder on Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My question is simple, but I don't know how to do, for example, in my code, I pull my images from a website I'm using this `icon: 'http://i45.tinypic.com/2yua8ns.png'` I want to use something like this: `icon: '\images/image.png'`

How I call this using javascript on a HTML dreamweaver script ?

EDIT: Solves, dont need the "\" on the start, the right way is this:   `icon: 'images/image.png'`

Comment: what is a `HTML dreamweaver script`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're trying to do? You can use relative urls like so `/images/image.png` will be relative to the application root, and `images/image.png` will be relative to the current execution location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imagelocation = window.location.hostname + foo.icon;
```

where `foo` is the object that contains the property `icon`.

Comment: Thanks, solved, but I used this: icon: 'Images/image.png' the problem was with the \ on the start